# Get filename of *.json in variable in gulp task

Tags: json, path, gulp

I have a structure of home.json, contact.json, case.json etc. in each directory and I am merging this into one, like home-combined.json.

I need to get the filename of `*.json` to set the fileName to `*-combined.json`, i'm using this pageName variable to get the name of the file but the outcome is `*-combined.json` instead of `home-combined.json`

```
gulp.task('json-merge',['json'], function(){

    return gulp.src(directories.src + '/json-combined/**/*.json')
    var file = directories.src + '/json-combined/**/*.json'
    var pageName = path.basename(file, path.extname(file))

    .pipe(jsonMerge({
      fileName: pageName + '-combined.json',
      edit: function(parsedJson, file) {
        var component = path.basename(path.dirname(file.path)); 
        var editedJson = {};
        editedJson[camelCase(component)] = parsedJson; 
        return editedJson;
      }
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.json.dest))
});
```

Comment: Your `var`s are sandwiched into the stream... that cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are doing I would do the following if you are trying to do this:

home.json

```
{
  one: 1
}
```

other.json

```
{
  two: 2
}
```

and you want to get:
home-combined.json

```
{
  one: 1,
  two: 2
}
```

Use this gulp module https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json

An example in your case would be :

```
 var jsonmerge = require('gulp-merge-json');
 var paths = require('./pathsFile.json');

 /*
  Basic functionality
 */
 gulp.task('json-merge', function(){
   return gulp.src('jsonFiles/**/*.json')
          .pipe(jsonmerge('home-combined.json')) 
          .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.json.dest));
 });
```

The only difference here would be that you would not need to specify the name of the file to be parsed.

Not sure if this answers your question, but if you specify what you need I can edit my response.

--Edit
To get files from different directories with gulp you can specify where the stream is coming from for example:

```
  return gulp.src([dir1 + 'jsonFiles/**/*.json', 
                   dir2 + 'jsonFiles/**/*.json', 
                   dir3 + 'jsonFiles/**/*.json'])
```

Comment: I have several home.json and other.json spread over jsonFiles/**/, for example 
jsonFile/component-1/home.json, jsonFile/component-1/other.json jsonFile/component-2/home.json, jsonFile/component-1/other.json jsonFile/component-3/home.json, jsonFile/component-3/other.json etc. 

and would like to merge these into home-combined.json/other-combined.json so I will need the name of the json file to create the filename in my edit function.

Comment: Ok I understand what you meant now, although I would recommend against trying to pick out files from the blob stream,  as at the end of the day you are parsing a blob that contains multiple files, which are coming in no specific order. It is possible to pick and choose what you want, but might be a bigger hassle than what it is worth. Having said that since you know the directory and what files you want. I would suggest creating different gulp tasks for each combined json file. And combining all calls to one gulp array that you can call in watch and your default tasks or gulp cli.